# Sending a symbol from guard-cucumber as the icon to ruby_gntp causes a crash

Tags: ruby, cucumber, guard, growl

I am using ruby_gntp to send notifications and it works for RSpec, but Cucumber is causing the exception below.

In this case, icon is :passed and type is "Notification".

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into String (TypeError)
/home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby_gntp-0.3.4/lib/ruby_gntp.rb:271:in `exists?'
/home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby_gntp-0.3.4/lib/ruby_gntp.rb:271:in `handle_icon'
/home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby_gntp-0.3.4/lib/ruby_gntp.rb:214:in `notify_header'
/home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby_gntp-0.3.4/lib/ruby_gntp.rb:111:in `notify'
/home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.7/lib/notiffany/notifier/gntp.rb:63:in `_perform_notify'
```

I am not sure if passing a symbol to ruby_gntp is bad, or if it is OK and if ruby_gntp should be able to convert that to an icon.

What is the problem here?

[enter link description here](https://github.com/guard/guard-cucumber/issues/27)

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just open an issue in GitHub (Notiffany project) for stuff like this.

I'd say Notiffany shouldn't pass a symbol, so I created this issue: https://github.com/guard/notiffany/issues/19

Also, ruby_gntp hasn't been updated for years, while Guard::Notiffany is part of the Guard project. So it's more likely it will be fixed and released there.